# Data layout on WPF DataGrid when binding to Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I am binding a WPF DataGrid to Entities through Entity Framework. I do not find a way to present data on the DataGrid the way I want to and I cannot/do not want to touch the source database data or entities.

The generated Entity Model has only one table ("Table1") with the following properties:

```
ID (Int64)
Date (DateTime)
Item1 (Decimal)
Item2 (Decimal)
Item3 (Decimal)
```

in XAML I have:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="listOfItems" Source="{Binding}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

and:

```
<DataGrid Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource listOfItems}}">
</DataGrid>
```

and I set the Source for CollectionViewSource in code:

```
CType(Me.FindResource("listOfItems"), CollectionViewSource).Source = context.Table1.ToList()
```

(context being declared earlier, not shown here)

That way I get the DataGrid filled properly but I want to display data differenctly on UI.
This is how it is displayed now on DataGrid (top row being the header on DataGrid):

```
ID    Date      Item1    Item2    Item3
1     1.1.2000  100      200      300
2     2.1.2000  101      201      301
3     3.1.2000  102      202      302
4     4.1.2000  103      203      303
5     5.1.2000  104      204      304
```

But I need to display it as:

```
       1.1.2000  2.1.2000  3.1.2000  4.1.2000  5.1.2000
Item1  100       101       102       103       104
Item2  200       201       202       203       204   
Item3  300       301       302       303       304
```

How can I achieve this? 
Tried to explore the CollectionViewSource options with no luck. Or do I need to generate a completely new list of objects/entities for this (hopefully no)?. 
Data on the DataGrid is editable by the user and must be persisted eventually back to database through EF and I think creating a view (=readonly) in the database is therefore out of question.